# Convert variable list of arguments to integers (Python)

Tags: python, type-conversion, arguments

I have a function that takes a variable number of arguments and returns the sum. I want it to be able to take all types that can be converted to an integer (string, float, etc.)

It looks like this:

```py
def addition(*numbers: int):
    return sum(numbers)
```

It works when I use only integers:

```py
>>> addition(1, 2, 3)
6
```

But as soon as I start using strings or mixed types I get an error:

```py
>>> addition("1", "2", 3)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Does the `*numbers: int` typecasting not work on variable arguments or am I doing something wrong? Of course, I could loop over the argument list and explicitly convert but  I'd prefer not to do that if I can avoid it.

Comment: `sum(map(int, numbers))`

Comment: It's NOT typecasting. It's type hinting, meaniing it won't do the cast automatically for you.

Comment: And the hint is wrong, it should be `List[int]`

Comment: So it doesn't do the conversion because it's an argument list or because I did the hint wrong? I did `numbers: typing.Iterable[int]` that didn't work either. @Jab's solution did, though

Comment: Again, read Justin's comment.  A type hint is just that; it is *not* a conversion command.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now, for some reason I thought it would convert for me. Never too late to unlearn bad habits...

Comment: It doesn't do the conversion because Python is strongly typed; it won't implicitly convert a value of one type to another, *but* the types involved may implement `__add__` to define what it would mean to, for example, add a `str` and an `int` value. Neither `str.__add__` or or `int.__add__` do that, however, so it is up to you to explicitly convert arguments as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def addition(*numbers):
    new_numbers = []
    for number in numbers:
        number = int(number)
        new_numbers.append(number)
    return sum(new_numbers)
```

All arguments for the function are converted to integers.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is type hinting typecasting in the sense you are thinking is not a part of python it wont check the input it is merely a hint for the coder that an integer is supposed to be the input.

I suggest trying to change the numbers to int and if it fails throw an error:

```
def addition(*numbers):
    try:
        return sum(map(int, numbers))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Supposed to input values that can be casted to ints")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet will convert input to int and sum the values using `reduce` if you are using `Python 3.0.1` or above version

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

def sum(*numbers):
    try:
        return reduce(add, map(int, numbers))
    except TypeError as e:
        return default
```

Example:

```
sum("1", 5.00, 10)
```

Output:

```
16
```

Hope this will helpful for you.